# why my buttons suddenly get bigger when i use Android studio

Tags: button, size

ok , let's say i have 2 buttons and Textview between them.

and the button width = 60dp height = 45dp

sometimes my buttons becomes too BIG! but the width and height did not change in my xml !

is this an android studio bug ?

Comment: Is there some kind of zoom/scaling setting?

Comment: can you share screenshots?

Comment: i will take screenshots next time , but when it happens i just press CTRL + Z twice then my problem solved .. even if i didn't touch the xml files! it's just weird!